# Fixed Buffer disappears after closing QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer

Has anyone else experienced this problem and knows how to solve it?
When I reopen QGIS the buffer layer is still there but the buffer lines themselves are not shown in the map anymore.

Comment: Did you save the created buffer to a file? Did you save the project before closing it? Did you change the style of the buffer?

Comment: Saving the buffer did the job. I was assuming that the buffer would be saved automatically. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

It's probably because layers created from Processing algorithms (like Buffer) are temporary. If you are happy with the result of the buffer, you should right click on the buffer layer in the layer list after it is created and select "Export as" (or "Save as" depending on version) and save the layer.

This behaviour allows you to experiment with different settings for the processing algorithms without filling up your hard drive with temporary files. The caveat is that you have to manually save the final, desired result as outlined above.

Comment: In QGIS 3.4 there is a handy "Make permanent" option when you right click on the temporary layer.